# Do wordpress loop with a specific term

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

How can I do the wordpress post loop, using a custom post type, to display only post from a certain category of a custom taxonomy?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'taxonomy' => 'newscat',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query -> have_posts()):while($query -> have_posts()):$query -> the_post();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arguments are incorrect.

Try this.

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'news',
 'posts_per_page' => 6,
 'tax_query' => array(
    array(
     'taxonomy' => 'newscat',
     'field' => 'slug',
     'terms' => 'news'
  ),
 ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query -> have_posts()):while($query -> have_posts()):$query -> the_post();
```